# Command can't open my file even though the user has permissions to

Tags: server, vmware

I tried so many different things. Look:

```
eu@ubuntu-n:/mnt/hgfs/eupa$ ls -la docker-compose.yml 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 eu eu 325 Jul 11 07:05 docker-compose.yml
eu@ubuntu-n:/mnt/hgfs/eupa$ docker compose up
open /mnt/hgfs/eupa/docker-compose.yml: permission denied
```

This `/mnt/hgfs` is being mounted by the command: `sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,auto_unmount`

What could it be? I tried so many things. I doubt it's a bug in vmhfs-fuse.

Comment: Is it actually mounted read-write? Also: try `strace docker compose up` and look at the last lines to see what the actual file permissions failure is. The error message might not be the whole story.

Comment: The user must have read access to each directory along the path from `/`. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.